# Delete in cascade

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to asp.net and mvc.
I have a class AsyApp

```
 public class AsyApp
{
    [Key]
    public int AsyAppId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Nom")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Scene> Scenes { get; set; }
}
```

It has a collection of scenes

```
 public class Scene
{

    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int SceneId { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("AsyApp")]
    public int AsyAppId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual AsyApp AsyApp { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("Name")]
    public int NameId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Nom")]
    public virtual Translation Name { get; set; }

    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

And the Scene has a property Name from a class Translation

```
public class Translation
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int TranslationId { get; set; }

    public string Fr { get; set; }
    public string En { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my issue.
I will use the class Translation to handle language  for every single string in my application. I could be in any other classes

I would like that when I delete an application, it delete the appropriate scenes and localisations

Here is my code for deleting an app

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        AsyApp asyApp = db.AsyApps.Find(id);
        if (asyApp == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        db.AsyApps.Remove(asyApp);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

The scenes seams to be deleted automaticaly but not the localisations associated with them...

Hope you can help me

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

look at this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#CascadeDelete

you can enable cascade delete using Fluent API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I was aware of this, but does this mean that I have to do a rule for every single Translation property ??